# Today is missing

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

I saw I had got 20 rep, and clicked on the reputation link in the dropdown.

The reputation tab in my profile isn't showing Today at all, no way, no how.

[image]

It showed up with next upvote, but the 20 is still missing. I was paying attention because I was so close to the cap. The 20 is also missing from the reputation check page. My only thought right now is that someone changed two old downvotes to upvotes, but I'm not sure if that would show that way or not (and it'd be a true difference of 16).

Here's a pic of the reputation dropdown showing the 30 rep (after the third upvote).

[image]

**Edit:** I'm now up to 60 rep in the reputation dropdown, and the Today link is showing (which it started doing at 30), but it still only counts up to 40 rep.

**SOLVED:** A [two-upvote answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99365/i-got-banned-from-stackoverflow-i-cant-understand-why-i-have-349-points/99383#99383) (10ks only) was part of a deleted question (another swept under the rug plea/complaint).  So there is a bug where Today didn't show, after all the rep I had Today got deleted.

**How about we show the deleted rep in the reputation report shaded, like they do for deleted posts in the flag report?**

Comment: It's been long enough now that I doubt it's a caching issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The cause here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99365/i-got-banned-from-stackoverflow-i-cant-understand-why-i-have-349-points/99383#99383) is correct, though we don't intend to change the reputation changes on deleted content in the reputation report or the profile reputation graph...it would make things even *more* confusing.

We have a long-term plan to improve the way we store reputation history in general (e.g. it's accurate all the time), but it's not something we'll get to in the next month (at a minimum), it'll take a non-trivial time investment and we're just lacking on spare time at the moment.

**Update:** these changes are now live, reputation will be kept in sync for cases like this.

Comment: thanks for the response, I always understand `lacking on spare time`.  I think your link is going to the wrong place, might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that StackOverflow's system is being cached hardly, however, your case is different. It's same with cap. Sometimes I receive more reputation than I should have. You can take a look at [/reputation/](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation/) & maybe recount your reputation when this happens again

(on stackoverflow I have ▾genesis 5,571 reputation BUT 5524 real repuation ;))